# How to reset git author recent two commits?

Tags: git, rebase

When I commit changed files, one more commit is made automatically after pull(or fetch) if there is no conflict btw remote and local repo.

In that situation, how can I change author or email both commits before push?

I know how change contents, commit message, author, email.., of the recent commit as follow,

```
git commit --amend -m "hahaha"
git commit --amend --reset-author // reset author & author by configured
```

But this command fix contents of auto-merged commit. I don't know the way to fix contents of what I committed.

ps.

I already try rebase -i (id for what I committed). It shows as below.

```
pick (id which is the recent commit in remote server, not mine) "commit message....."
```

But I'm beginner for git, I don't know exact meaning of that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The -i flag to `git rebase` mean interactive, not id.  It means an editor will be spawned where you can make changes to the commits (squash them, remove commits entirely, edit their comments, etc).

Comment: Also, please include the `git rebase -i` command that you used.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to amend the a commit before the HEAD commit then you need to use `git rebase`.  In your example you made a commit on your local branch.  In your upstream several new commits were made since you last pull.  Now, when you pull, you will get a merge commit in addition to the commits made in the upstream.  So, after the pull you have something like:

```
* merge commit (HEAD)
|\
* | your commit
| * someone else's commit
|/
* common merge ancestor
```

From you description I take it that you would like to amend the "your commit" in the above.  When rebasing you always want to start with the commit just before the first commit you want to change.  So, to do this execute the following:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~~
```

This means "start a rebase on the first parent of the first parent of the first parent of HEAD, in this case the commit the rebase will start at is the "common merge ancestor" commit in the above.  You can also specify a tag, a branch, a commit hash, or anything other reference that resolves to a commit in place of `HEAD~~`.

With the `-i` option rebase will spawn an editor (vim, nano, etc) to edit the commits.  Here's some sample output:

```
pick a7681b2 merge commit
pick 10b5421 your commit

# Rebase c9e3a52..10b5421 onto c9e3a52
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

(if you would like to use a different editor than is run by default then set the `EDITOR` environment variable to whatever editor you prefer, for example in my `.bashrc` I have `export EDITOR=vim`)

So, in order to amend "your commit" you just replace "pick" with "edit":

```
pick a7681b2 merge commit
edit 10b5421 your commit
```

Then when you save the file rebase will checkout that commit and allow you to run whatever `git commit amend` commands that you want.  Once you've edited the commit to your liking run `git rebase --continue`.

One final note, its seems that on a `git pull` of this nature you expect a merge commit to be created.  You can get around this, and have a cleaner history, by doing `git pull --rebase` which will automatically rebase your commit on top of your upstream's HEAD.  If you did this your history would look like this instead of what I put in above:

```
* your commit
* someone else's commit
* common merge ancestor
```

Doing `git pull --rebase` is mandatory in many shops who want their git history to be as linear as possible.

Comment: `git rebase -i -p` to preserve the merge commit